# How do you add onchange action to collection_select?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have the following select drop down in my rails. I'm following the syntax from the API( http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select):

collection_select(object, method, collection, value_method, text_method, options = {}, html_options = {})

```
<%= collection_select(:sources, :source_id, Source.all, :id, :name, :include_blank => "Please select a source...", html_options = {:onchange => "updateTextArea()"} ) %>

function updateTextArea(){
 alert('source changed')
}
```

I'm able to get the drop down to display just fine with the values from the DB when I don't include html_options. However, I'm stuck trying to get an onchange action to occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think options needs to be in a hash (the part you have `include_blank` in currently). Try changing this

```
<%= collection_select(:sources, :source_id, Source.all, :id, :name, :include_blank => "Please select a source...", html_options = {:onchange => "updateTextArea()"} ) %>
```

to this

```
<%= collection_select(:sources, :source_id, Source.all, :id, :name, options = {include_blank: "Please select a source..."}, html_options = {:onchange => "updateTextArea()"} ) %>
```

Comment: This got me past the syntax exception, however it doesn't give me an alert dialogue, so I'm not sure why the function is not triggered when I change the drop down values.

Comment: My mistake, my <script> tag was not closed. Works accordingly now.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that in place of `options =` or `html_options =` you need to pass actual hash itself (like you actually did with `include_blank => true`). I would only explicitly mark those hashes with curly braces to separate them:

```
<%= collection_select(:sources, :source_id, Source.all, :id, :name, { :include_blank => "Please select a source..."}, {:onchange => "updateTextArea()"} ) %>
```

Hope this helps.

EDIT:

I forgot to add that if `updateTextArea()` JS function is not bind to a window there might be a problem with picking it up (I had similar problems in the past). For safety I would also do (if you are not using CoffeScript):

```
window.updateTextArea = function() { /* Your code */ }
```